# Using for loops

Tags: javascript

`alert(cellvalue)` shows three seperate pop ups:

`-10-|Car|*POB*[,]-20-|Bus|*CLR*`

`-22-|Car|*CLR*[,]-5-|Bus|*POB*`

`-12-|Car|*POB*[,]-55-|Bus|*CLR*`

I am then splitting these values and getting the three values I need as follows:-

```
            var array = cellvalue.split("[,]");
            var start_carStat = array[0].indexOf('*') + 1;
            var end_carStat = array[0].indexOf('*',start_carStat);
            var text_carStat = array[0].substring(start_carStat,end_carStat);
```

alert(text_carNum); shows '10', '22', '12'

```
            var start_carNum2 = array[1].indexOf('-') + 1;
            var end_carNum2 = array[1].indexOf('-',start_carNum2);
            var text_carNum2 = array[1].substring(start_carNum2,end_carNum2);
```

alert(text_carNum); shows '20', '5', '55'

and then returning them as follows:-

```
return (text_carNum+', '+text_carNum2);
```

Since there could be upto 20 values in each array I am trying to use a for loop to achieve the same thing but I can't seem to get it to work.

At the moment I have:-

```
            for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
                var start_carNum = array[i].indexOf('-') + 1;
                var end_carNum = array[i].indexOf('-',start_carNum);
                var text_carNum = array[i].substring(start_carNum,end_carNum);

                return (text_carNum);
            }
```

with this alert(text_carNum) only shows '10','22','12'.

Any ideas on how I could get this to work the same way as above using for/each?

(hoping I have explained this clear enough)

Comment: <span style="color:'+color+'" !important;> Should be <span style="color:'+color+' !important;">

Comment: You are `return`ing from *inside* the `for` loop.  This will stop it after the 1st iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `return` in your loop, so the function exits at the end of the first iteration. You have to concatenate all values in a variable :

```
        var str_return = '';
        for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            var start_carNum = array[i].indexOf('-') + 1;
            var end_carNum = array[i].indexOf('-',start_carNum);
            var text_carNum = array[i].substring(start_carNum,end_carNum);

            str_return += '<span style="color:'+color+' !important;">'+text_carNum +'</span>';
        }
        return str_return;
```

BTW, notice that I change the last line : the `style` attribute was closed (double quote) just after the color, it has to be closed after `!important`.

Answer (score 2):

`return` will always exit the function as soon as it is called. In your code, it is only able to reach `array[0]` before it leaves the loop.

A solution would be to append the values of `array` to another variable within your loop, and then return a value *after* the loop has finished.